# The PHP error log has stopped working. It did work

Tags: php, apache, error-log

It's been working for ages and stopped.  I must be missing something obvious.

File */etc/php5/apache2/php.ini* relevant settings are:

```
display_errors = On  (I am not sure if this makes a difference)
log_errors = On
error_log = "/var/www/error_log.log"
```

In my code I have:

```
echo 'About to log';
error_log('An error');
```

I see "About to log" on the page, but nothing in the error log. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check out error_reporting(); it may help or it may not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Restart the Web server. Until you do `php.ini` changes are not considered.

Also, if you want to track PHP errors, you need to have `track_errors=On` and `error_reporting=E_ALL`, although that is not related with `error_log` calls. Also make sure that the error log file is writeable by the Web server user.

Comment: The file wasn't writable, I forgot I deleted and recreated it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

It ended up being permission issues.  The file grew too big to open quickly, so I deleted and recreated it, but with read-only permissions.

I totally forgot I deleted it. What a pain.

Comment: Had the same.... thank you for the hint. Had to create the log file manually and set owner/group to "www-data" (Ubuntu),

Comment: It also took a `service apache2 restart` for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my *php.ini* file (XAMPP default), there was a second entry for `error_log` overriding the one that I had set.

So if the other answers do not work for you too, search again for multiple entries of the necessary settings.