# PHP 5.3.9 log_errors not working, not saving errors in log file in Debian Lenny

Tags: php, apache, logging

I wanted to switch off display_errors in my production environment in my php ini file and save errors in a log file instead. After trying for hours without success I decided to ask for suggestions.

What I did:

in the loaded ini file according to php info:

```
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/apache2/php.errors
error_reporting=E_ALL

(file exists, is writable and chown to apache user www-data)
```

restarted apache

Generated an fatal error, function undefined.

checked the log file but nothing got saved, the log file is 0kb

In phpinfo() I have error_reporting=30711

Any suggestions? Did I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072987/php-error-log-not-working
(it could help eh, you've to try)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a directory writable from Apache. Try something like this

```
mkdir /var/log/php
chown www-data /var/log/php
```

in php.ini

```
error_log = /var/log/php/php_errors.log
```

Remember to rotate /var/log/php/php_errors.log

Comment: rotate? the location: why?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the apache2 directory is owned by root and does not have read/execution permissions for users other than those in the group. So, even though the php.errors file exists and is writeable, because its containing directory is not accessible www-data can not write to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem, the log will work if you choose syslog on php.ini

Comment: If I choose syslog on php.ini, how can I access the log on a Debian Lenny box? sorry, maybe newbie question

Comment: its in /var/log, my setup logs to more than on file, user.log is one of them.

Comment: made it work with syslog, thanks a lot. I would like to know the reason of my problem though. It will be handy using my own error log file. Thanks

Comment: I have a suspicion that is suhosin related (but not sure), do you have it installed ?